# How do I add value to my ligthning input using aura:iteration during onChange event of text box

Tags: salesforce

Hi I'm new to salesforce. I'm trying to develop a lightning component that will take user input, process that input & will display the value in two text box.My lightning component looks like

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" access="global" controller="VisionController">
<!--Remember to define your binding attribute-->
<aura:attribute name="val" type="String"/>
<lightning:card title="Partner Information">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <p>
            <!--Set you attribute as the value of the lightning:input component-->
            <lightning:input aura:name="val" 
                             label ="Enter KPI" 
                             value="{!v.val}" 
                             type="text" 
                             onchange="{!c.onChange}"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

My JS controller looks like

```
({
onChange : function(component, event, helper) {

var action = component.get("c.getCallKPI")
    action.setParams({
        "value":val,

    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action)

}
```

})

I tried to do the iteration portion in controller using following code

```
 var prediction=component.find("pred")
    var predictionProb=component.find("predProb")
 <aura:iteration items="{c.getCallKPI}" var="predUrl" >
        prediction.value="{!predUrl.label}"
        predictionProb.value="{!prediction.probability}"
    </aura:iteration>
```

where prediction & predictionProb are  id of two lightning inputs given in my component.But I'm getting syntax error at `</aura:iteration>`

If I'm doing it in component using following code

```
 <aura:iteration items="{c.getCallKPI}" var="predUrl" >

            <lightning:input id="pred" readonly="true"  value="{!predUrl.label}"/>
            <lightning:input id="predProb" readonly="true" value="{!predUrl.probability}" />

    </aura:iteration>
```

Then it's not giving any error but not populating the inputs.
Can you guide how do I resolve this?

my getCallKPI is given below

```
@auraEnabled
public static List<KPI.Prediction> getCallKPI(string value) {

    return KPI.Prediction;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use aura:iteration inside component markup.

1. In your component create new attribute of type "List".

   ```
   <aura:attribute name="predictions" type="List"/>
   ```
2. In JS controller specify callback for action, in which set new attribute to *response.getReturnValue()*.

   ```
   action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      component.set("v.predictions", response.getReturnValue());
   }
   ```

   [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)
3. Inside component, iterate over returned records:

   ```
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.predictions}" var="item">
    //your logic
   </aura:iteration>
   ```

   [aura:iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration/documentation)

Comment: Thaks xedshot.In aura iteration I have added this thing `{!item.label}  {!item.predictions} ` But it's not showing anything.I also put a `system.debug inside my `getCallKPI` and it's returning `Inside Predict Internal label: (Prediction:[label=Persian cat, probability=0.79763365],....)` Can you please let me know what wrong I'm doing?

Comment: @Sonia It looks like your getCallKPI method doesn't return proper list. Could you provide the whole getCallKPI method ?

Comment: please share with me your mail id then I will forward you the actual code. I have given dummy code here